# query errors out if ran from shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, impala

I can run this query fine

```
CREATE TABLE db.table1 STORED AS PARQUET as 
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE UPPER(executing) = 'TRUE';
```

Unless I run it from bash shell script. I get this error

```
#!/bin/bash

bash -c 'impala-shell -k -q "CREATE TABLE db.table1 STORED AS PARQUET as
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE UPPER(executing) = 'TRUE';"'
```

> ERROR: AnalysisException: operands of type STRING and BOOLEAN are not
>   comparable: upper(executing) = TRUE

I have tried using double quotes, no quotes and lower case with no luck

Comment: You cannot put a single-quote inside a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes *cannot* be included in a single-quoted string in shell. The single quotes around `TRUE` aren't included in the SQL command passed to `impala-shell`; the first closes the initial `'`, and the second starts a new quoted string, so your script is equivalent to

```
bash -c "impala-shell -k -q \"CREATE TABLE db.table1 STORED AS PARQUET as
SELECT * from db.table WHERE UPPER(executing) = TRUE;\""
```

One solution is to use double quotes as I have above, which allow you to include the single quotes that SQL requires.

```
bash -c "impala-shell -k -q \"CREATE TABLE db.table1 STORED AS PARQUET as
SELECT * from db.table WHERE UPPER(executing) = 'TRUE';\""
```

Alternatively, use `$'...'` to quote the argument to `-c`, in which case you can include properly escaped single quotes in the string.

```
bash -c $'impala-shell -k -q "CREATE TABLE db.table1 STORED AS PARQUET as
SELECT * from db.table WHERE UPPER(executing) = \'TRUE\';"'
```

However it's not clear why you are using `bash -c` at all instead of just running `impala-shell` directly as:

```
impala-shell -k -q "CREATE ... WHERE UPPER(executing) = 'TRUE';"
```